# how to slide image in jquery in html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 images like a.jpg ,b.jpg and c.jpg. In this images i want to used a j query and  slid the images. The images is rotating one by one. in this slider i want 3 bottom also. So please reply this...

Comment: Try the [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Show what you have tried and where the problem is and we will help you. "I want" is no question.

Answer (score 0):

Googling for "jquery slide" gives you a) a function reference for jquery and example code on the docs how to do those effects and b) a hell of a result list for ready-to-use sliders.

http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use "ContentSlider" to slide images...
Below link covers the implementation part of ContentSlider....

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/featuredcontentslider.htm